# Search doesn't work on php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am testing some basic searching on tables without the use of database yet.

The problem is the search is working in the HTML file but failed to work on php file(I am using codeigniter framework).

This is the code on both html file:

```
 <script src="js/search.js"></script>
```

THis is the code on my CI php VIEW file:

script type="text/javascript" src="application/views/ui/js/search.js">

My htaccess file on the views:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /webs/BCI/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My base_url function works on my css files, but it just won't load my JS files located on my js folder.
Are there any more configurations needed to load a js file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store all `css`, `js` and `image` file under `public_html` folder. And call your file like-

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/search.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have stored all css,js, and image in a folder called ui, I have been successful on loading my css files using the echo base_url() thing, but I cant seem to load my js file.

Comment: the `ui` folder must be below `document root`.

Comment: I have tried it still fails to have a result in the search of the php file

Comment: It should work. For test add a `test.js` file and put here `alert('works');` and check it.

Comment: The loading of js file worked. Thank you but unfortunately it seems the error wasn't in the loading of js file but on the search itself. Thanks btw